# How to store the results of a select statement and be able to use it again in another select statement PL\SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to store the result of a select statement (in temp memory maybe?) and then call the saved result and be able to use it again in other selects so it doesn't have to execute again and again which would increase the execution time. I was thinking maybe using a procedure or a cursor would be the solution, but I'm know enough SQL to be able to use it, any help would be helpful!

Here is the select statement that I would like to store:

```
select "PO Number2", "Total"

from (select distinct "PO Number2", sum("Amount") as "Total"

      from (select distinct account as Account,
                            company as Company,
                            year_period_key as "Year Period Key",
                            voucher_no as "Voucher No",
                            voucher_type as "Vou Type",
                            voucher_date as "GRN/Invoice Date",
                            reference_number as "PO Number2",
                            code_c as "Project ID",
                            ifsapp.PURCHASE_ORDER_API.Get_Vendor_No(reference_number) as "Supplier ID",
                            ifsapp.SUPPLIER_INFO_API.Get_Name(ifsapp.PURCHASE_ORDER_API.Get_Vendor_No(reference_number)) as "Supplier Name",
                            sum(quantity) as "Quantity",
                            sum(amount) as "Amount",
                            sum(debet_amount) as "Debit Amount",
                            sum(credit_amount) as "Credit Amount"

              from ifsapp.GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY

             where account = '222010'
               and Voucher_Type = '0'

             group by voucher_type,
                      account,
                      year_period_key,
                      voucher_date,
                      reference_number,
                      code_c,
                      company,
                      voucher_no,
                      party_type_id

            union all

            select distinct account as Account,
                            company as Company,
                            year_period_key as "Year Period Key",
                            voucher_no as "Voucher No",
                            voucher_type as "Vou Type",
                            voucher_date as "GRN/Invoice Date",
                            ifsapp.MAN_SUPP_INVOICE_API.Get_Purchase_Order_Ref_Number(company,
                                                                                      party_type_id,
                                                                                      'Supplier',
                                                                                      reference_number) as "PO Number2",
                            code_c as "Project ID",
                            ifsapp.PURCHASE_ORDER_API.Get_Vendor_No(ifsapp.MAN_SUPP_INVOICE_API.Get_Purchase_Order_Ref_Number(company,
                                                                                                                              party_type_id,
                                                                                                                              'Supplier',
                                                                                                                              reference_number)) as "Supplier ID",
                            ifsapp.SUPPLIER_INFO_API.Get_Name(ifsapp.PURCHASE_ORDER_API.Get_Vendor_No(ifsapp.MAN_SUPP_INVOICE_API.Get_Purchase_Order_Ref_Number(company,
                                                                                                                                                                party_type_id,
                                                                                                                                                                'Supplier',
                                                                                                                                                                reference_number))) as "Supplier Name",
                            sum(quantity) as "Quantity",
                            sum(amount) as "Amount",
                            sum(debet_amount) as "Debit Amount",
                            sum(credit_amount) as "Credit Amount"

              from ifsapp.GEN_LED_VOUCHER_ROW_UNION_QRY

             where account = '222010'
               and Voucher_Type = 'J'
             group by voucher_type,
                      account,
                      year_period_key,
                      voucher_date,
                      reference_number,
                      code_c,
                      company,
                      voucher_no,
                      party_type_id)

     where "Year Period Key" <= '&YearPeriodKey'
     group by "PO Number2")

where "Total" = 0
```

Thanks In advance! :)

Comment: look into materialized views

Comment: Use hint `/*+ RESULT_CACHE */`

Comment: Just notice: result cache only works with Oracle enterprise edition

Comment: I recommend you take a look into deterministic functions

Comment: @tbone - ...or global temp tables...

Comment: Why do you think you want to store the results of a query? How many rows will this query return? Can the data returned by the query be changed by some other process while the results are "stored"? If so, should or should not those changes be reflected in the "stored" data?

Comment: @BobJarvis true, temp tables might work too (or even better depending on the situation), but can be tricky unless you know what you're doing (handling multiple sessions, transactions, etc).

Comment: @BobJarvis only want to store the results temporarily so the query doesn't need to run again, as i'm using the same query in a few more select statements and it does return a lot of rows... takes about 12minutes to run atm. So if the query runs once and just reuses the resulting data in the other queries it would complete quicker.. in theory, thanks.

Comment: Because you want to make this data available for a relatively short time I suggest that you take a look at using global temporary tables. [Oracle docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633) and [a good write-up at Oracle-Base here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has it's own optimizers that help you not perform the same query multiple times. It'll store the results on the server memory (limited) if the query is exactly the same. So if you perform this query 5 times in one minute, it'll will not consume many resources. In advance, you should see if a materialized view does not solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to "store" the result and re-use within a single session or to store the result for other sessions to re-use. To materialize teh query data such that it becomes visible to other sessions, and remains so until such time as a refresh is invoke (manually or scehudled), then really you're looking at materialised views. If this is just for the purpose of a single session/job and prevent having to re-query the data repeatedly, remember that with ref-cursors you can only go forwards. You could write the data to a PLSQL table (array/collection), but if the dataset is large, watch out for memory. For larger datasets, probably the best bet are temporary tables.